# How to implement search inside a json Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json array like this

```
[
  {"Id":1,
  "Name":"John"
  }, 
  {"Id":2,
  "Name":"Mathew"
  },
   {"Id":3,
  "Name":"Wilfred"
  },
   {"Id":4,
  "Name":"Gary"
  }
]
```

I need to implement an auto complete feature using this data. 
so if I search for `"Wil"` I should get `Wilfred` as result. How can I do such a search similar to the SQL `LIKE` in JSON array

Comment: How about `Array#filter` ?

Comment: Did you already try something ? Do you need to search on several properties (Name, Firstname etc...) ?

Comment: If you apply datatable it is inbuilt in search box.

Comment: @R.Foubert nope. For now I don't want to search on several properties

Comment: @Rishi It is just simple autocomplete. Don't want to make it complex

Comment: Use jquery autocomple plugin and pass you json object as a source

Comment: According to Rayon, you should use the filter method of the Array protoype. Then check if the name contains the input and return the object if so ;)

Comment: if using jquery, `$.grep(persons,function(obj) { return obj.Name.indexOf('Wil') != -1});`

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
var persons = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "John"
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Mathew"
}, {
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "Wilfred"
}, {
  "Id": 4,
  "Name": "Gary"
}]
var searchTerm = "Wil";
var results = persons.filter(function(person) {
  return person.Name.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: if you want a fuzzy search, I suggest you go with https://github.com/bripkens/fuzzy.js